# Ubuntu 16.04 LAN is not detected

Tags: networking, network-manager, lan, nmcli

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with i3 desktop environment. My `ifconfig` command shows the following output-

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:49:4f:16:2a  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:5a:da:d9:a8:24  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:124400 (124.4 KB)  TX bytes:124400 (124.4 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:00:86:ed  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Few days ago, I have updated my kernel and my system was unable to detect LAN. To solve that, I found a solution from askubuntu as-
**Solution 1**

```
nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

Now it worked fine for some days. Then I probably have updated my system(I forgot) and it stopped working. Again I found another solution to detect LAN.
**Solution 2**

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then it worked perfectly fine. I don't know, after some days, Solution 2 stopped working. So I found some random solution from internet, and it worked.
**Solution 3**

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 down
sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
sudo ifconfig docker0 down
sudo ifconfig lo down
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And after some days, it stopped working. Now I had to restart my system for LAN to work. And again that solution was for only some days. Now I am unable to find any other solutions which will keep my LAN port working. My system info is-

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I have explained the whole scene, because I had no idea about where the problem is. And I had tried every random solution from internet, as long as it was working. Please try to guess the actual problem, because it is getting worse day by day. If you need any other info, do mention in the comment section.
PS- I am sure it is a software problem. I have dual boot, and in windows, LAN is working perfectly fine.